# Internet slows down to unusable speed after opening any game

Tags: networking, windows-11, ping, connection

Update:

- 28/09/2023 - I did full scan of laptop with Microsoft defender and it found few viruses in some of the software i had downloaded ages ago. I removed them and then tried OSU, and Hitman 3 seemed to be working fine, but when I launch GeForce Experience app I get same issue, can't even log in to my NVidia account.

I really hope you guys can help me I've tried solutions from google and what not nothing seems to help. It is a really weird problem. So long story short, my internet behaves normally when windows boots, but if i open any game it slows down to basically unusable speeds.

**EDIT: Including specs of laptop as someone asked sorry i forgot before**

- It's a gaming laptop AORUS 7KB
- CPU Intel Core i7-10750H @ 2.6GHz
- OS Windows 11 Latest update (with copilot), but same issue was in previous version of win 11
- RAM 16GB
- GPU RTX 2060 and also Integrated Intel UHD Graphics
- 2 SSD's 512GB SX8200PNP-512GT-S (original) and 1TB Crucial CT1000P1SSD8 (added myself)

Example: I downloaded hitman 3 from xbox store, and tried launching it. It took me 5 min just to login into my xbox account from INSIDE the game and it failed few times before i succeded to log on, then i wasn't able to logon to IOI account because my connection was really slow.

**WHAT I'VE DONE SO FAR:**

1. I tried disabling firewall didn't help.
2. I disabled all non Microsoft services in msconfig and all auto start programs, and gave laptop a restart

Tried some running other programs which are not games and are causing same issue:

1. Google Earth program
2. Logitech G Hub (doesnt cause slowdown but program itself loads forever)

Here is a ping test i did to illustrate what happens with my connection I put some comments with # near ping changes to indicate what was I doing at the time of a change. Also I tried this with Teardown game, but same happens for Hitman 3, OSU, Forza Horizon 5 and tbh any game.

```
Pinging google.com [142.250.74.174] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=55ms TTL=56 # Below are normal pings when not many programs running just discord
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=60ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=57ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=60ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=53ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=71ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=65ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=60ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=63ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=60ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=49ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=62ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=66ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=47ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=64ms TTL=56
Request timed out. #here i opened teardown game. This happens just after launch
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=582ms TTL=56 # game loaded ping remains high
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=191ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=489ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=400ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=605ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=443ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=102ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=222ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=173ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=144ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=58ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=118ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=131ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=104ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=174ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=135ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=54ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=121ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=120ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=98ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=179ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=146ms TTL=56
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=62ms TTL=56
Request timed out. #Tried browsing in edge while game was still open
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 142.250.74.174: bytes=32 time=749ms TTL=56
Request timed out.
```

Included image of how my task manager WiFi Perfomance window looks.
Big spikes are when i opened youtube video and closed it after few seconds. Then I wasn't doing anything laptop was on standby so  the graph is barely moving, I don't really know if it's bad or not so I included picture for you guys to look.
[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148818/discussion-on-question-by-asdlh2-internet-slows-down-to-unusable-speed-after-ope); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is indicative of "Buffer Bloat" -- where your router queues packets for transmission, creating a long queue, which is why packets have such high latency to get through the queue.

If you do a "Buffer bloat" test, it will tell you that you have "Buffer bloat", but that just tells you what you already can see in your ping results -- it's not really able to tell if there is some other different reason for what you observe.

If you search for "Buffer bloat" on the internet, it will tell you that the solution is to use a different router. In any case, reading about "Buffer bloat" may help you identify where the problem is.

Comment: Cache bloat is a database issue. I think you mean [bufferbloat](https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/)

Comment: @Tetsujin : mind glitch.